# Adding multiple controls to AdditionalPageHead

Tags: development, feature, user-controls, delegate-control

My question is regarding the delegate control AdditionalPageHead, as we know it allows multple controls to be loaded.

My questions are:

- How to add multiple controls?
- I want that the different controls are activated by different future.

Example:
I have first.ascx which is deployed with site scoped feature1 and i have a second.ascx which is deployed with site scope feature2.

Is it possible so that the second.ascx is added to the first.ascx or the other way around?

Comment: What if I want to activate both on a site. will i see both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In feature 1 have an elements.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" 
           Sequence="90"             
           ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/XXX/first.ascx" />
</Elements>
```

In feature 2 have an elements.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" 
           Sequence="91"             
           ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/YYY/second.ascx" />
</Elements>
```

Sequence controls the order

Comment: What if I want to add both controls one after the other on the same site?

Comment: Please refer to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126204/load-multiple-controls-to-a-additionalpagehead. I am really stuck in a problem

Comment: Is it possible to have your scripts be loaded last? Currently I have sequence set at 9999 but my scripts get loaded before all the other SharePoint scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Im taking a shot in the dark here and presume this is for 2010

http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/create-an-additionalpagehead-control-packed-into-a-feature-in-visual-studio-2010/

hope it helps :)