# Limiting user to accept the agreement field and then proceed with site in sharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i have one StudentUser list in my site, having columns ("Name" varchar, "AD User" lookup, "Agree" checkbox).

Now what i need is when StudentUser List member login first time, the first view should be one "Term of Use Agreement", and that user will be only able to proceed, if agree with our agreement.

i have search some link, and on http://userredirect.codeplex.com/ i found a webpart for redirecting specific user group, but problem is its not completing my requirement.

Any type of suggestion will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

make a usercontrol do the "Agree" status check and show Agreement job.
then use **DelegateControl** with ID **AdditionalPageHead** to 'inject' the usercontrol to the master page, so every page will run your code!

Here's the more detail infomation:
[Adding multiple controls to AdditionalPageHead](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43971/adding-multiple-controls-to-additionalpagehead)

Comment: What if i don't want user to be block on every page, i mean the site is for anonymous access, and user who will agree the Terms will have some additional access to some areas, you can say application pages or site.

Comment: i think there's nothing different, if the `protected resource`  is a subsite[s] (`SPWeb`), set your feature scope to `SPWeb` and just active it in the sites. if the resource is some application page, just add conditions in your control to protect applications only.   if you just want to protect some application pages you own, not the OOB pages, just put your control in those pages!