# Load multiple controls to a AdditionalPageHead

Tags: 2013, delegate-control

I have 2 script files which I want to add to a site. I might add none, either of two or both.

Is there a way to do so by overriding the delegate control `AdditionalPageHead`?

Currently, I have 2 separate solutions overriding the delegate control. the only difference in the two solutions is

1. the path to the script
2. the sequence number

It works fine for activating one of the delegate control. But as soon as I activate both, the one with lower sequence number starts coming twice.

How can I make  the 2 different controls come simultaneously whose order is based on the sequence number?

Any other approach is welcome as long as it doesn't require master page or page layout changes.

Answer (score 0):

A Delegate control can contain sub controls.  Create your delegate and house your other two inside that, just like a text box or any other control.  Then control their visibility/activation from within the logic of the control.

I suppose you might need to control display based on feature activation, well you can have a hidden dependency feature on either of the two main features that is this Containing control feature, the visible features do nothing, the dependency feature can check to see if they are active to determine if to show the sub control it pertains to.  Don't like that myself but it's one way, I'd prefer another settings page in _layouts perhaps